# MySQL indexing for multiple count(*) queries

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, query-optimization

I'm lost regarding indexing.  I have a moderately complex web app that I'm building for a client and it has several count(*) queries that are all running very slow (0.3 seconds)

Here's a quick example

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS  `count` 
FROM  `vehicles` 
WHERE  `VehicleLocation_province` =  'Alberta'
AND  `default_image_URI` IS NOT NULL 
AND  `default_image_URI` !=  ''
```

Here's the explain..

```
 1 SIMPLE vehicles ref VehicleLocation_province,VehicleLocation_province_...     VehicleLocation_province 2 const 14128 Using where
```

I can't even get this query to use a proper index, never mind some of the more complex queries such as

```
SELECT * , ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( 53.543564 ) ) * COS( RADIANS( lat ) ) * COS( RADIANS( lng ) - RADIANS( - 113.490456 ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( 53.543564 ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( lat ) ) ) ) AS  `distance` 
FROM  `vehicles` 
WHERE  `Make` =  'Pontiac'
AND  `BodyStyle` =  'Sedan'
AND  `VehiclePrice` >=  '1'
AND  `VehiclePrice` <=  '36000'
AND  `VehiclePrice` IS NOT NULL 
AND  `default_image_URI` IS NOT NULL 
AND  `default_image_URI` !=  ''
HAVING `distance` < 50
ORDER BY `VehicleReceivedDate` DESC LIMIT 25
```

Explain

```
1 SIMPLE vehicles ref Make,BodyStyle,VehicleLocation_province_2 Make 99 const 5821 Using where; Using filesort
```

I know I need to avoid temp tables and filesorts where possible... but how is this practically accomplished when several of these count(*) queries must be executed on each request with varying where parameters grouping and ordering?

Comment: Is this InnoDB or MyISAM? They are completelly different in terms of performance, indexing and count(*).

Comment: @cherouvim, surely they are not completely different :) - some general rules should still apply

Comment: MyISAM. apparently count(*) performance is severely impacted in InnoDB (so I've read)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option which I hadn't considered (which I now view as the ideal solution) is the use a search server like Sphinx to handle the heavy lifting when if comes to indexing and performance.  Sphinx can do grouping and counting as well as fulltext and attribute searching/filtering on many columns in several different search configurations.

Sphinx can even do `@geodist` for radius calculations with `SetGeoAnchor ( $attrlat, $attrlong, $lat, $long )`

It makes little sense, when running complex search queries to attempt to re-invent the wheel and end up with ridiculous lists of multi-column indexes attempting to cover all manner of use cases.

I wish I'd thought of a search server earlier in the project-- now, it's a little late to save face on performance issues.

http://sphinxsearch.com

Answer (score 2):

Well, the only way to get indexes speed up queries is to have indexes cover enough conditions that the selectivity becomes useful (or for RDBMS to be able to use indexes to calculate aggregates such as count).

Do not fail to realize that having index on `(Make)` and index on `(BodyStyle)` is **not** the same as having index on `(Make, BodyStyle)`.

In your first query, when you need to count the records, the existence of index that covers `default_image_URI` and `VehicleLocation_province` should be enough for the mysql not to do a table scan, but retrieve the count from the index.

You can check this by creating an index `(VehicleLocation_province, default_image_URI)` and then running query and/or examining explain.

In the second query you have similar situation with query that has more conditions (which is good as long as they are all AND conditions) and it is not about counting records, but actually retrieving the data from the table and *sorting*.

Few notes here:

- notice your conditions `IS NOT NULL` and `!=''` - if these conditions are commonly present in your queries then these suggest that your design is not proper, and that you have denormalised different entities into one table so now you have to sort them out each time you want to use the data (this is just an indication, and I assume that you apply these conditions *a lot*, which might not be true)
- having said that, if you look at 2nd query and if Make and BodyStyle are covered with a composite index and have low selectivity the query will still perform fast
- mysql has to choose one index to access the data and it will try to choose the index that returns least number of rows given statistics and available conditions (so that further conditions have to loop through least number of records) - if that index helps only with reducing the resultset the sorting will be done using a filesort. For index to be useful for both selecting rows and sorting it should have useful order or indexed columns, for example in the above query index on `(Make, BodyStyle, VehicleReceivedDate)` might do the trick
- adding proper indexes on your table should help, but indexes can not fix problems with design

Comment: Explained very well.  I too like to explain how / why certain things happen instead of just giving an answer.

Comment: I found this article helpful in explaining the actual "rules" one must follow to get MySQL to use index with GROUPs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html  

On that note-- I have several queries running smoother now and a firmer understanding of multi-column index ordering.. 

This proj would greatly benefit from me going back and optimizing the model and somehow structuring the queries so they could use more general indexes.. I'm not sure of the theory behind that (with many variable parameters) Unfortunately, time on this project is about up.

Comment: Indexes + query cache seem to be doing the trick with adequate performance.  Thanks guys.

Comment: @FelixHCat, glad to help. Regarding the link, keep in mind it addresses GROUP BY specifically (your queries don't use it). Also, if my answer help feel free to upvote and accept it.

Comment: @FelixHCat, regarding query cache - it should be taken into consideration, but don't use it evaluate the performance - it will make execution time always zero on the second run if the resultset will be less then `query_cache_size` in my.cnf. Use `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE` to evaluate performance + EXPLAIN (or ideally use cache, but create realistic test workloads that will also do updates that will invalidate caches in a realistic way = which is not so trivial).

Comment: Yeah these prolly arn't good examples now that I look at them. ha. Many of the count(*) queries I'm using have groupings-- and one that I posted isn't a count(*) at all.  Oops *sigh* Anyway, the article goes through some great practical optimization.  And yes, I've gotten rid of the IS NOT NULLS since I realize that negation operators like that won't use indexes properly.

Comment: @Unreason yup no worries, I'm benchmarking queries before enabling the cache.